# RewriteRule não funciona com uma palavra específica

Tags: mod-rewrite

Apenas não funciona para "evento", mas se eu alterar para "evenTo" ele funciona, ex:

Não funciona

```
RewriteRule ^evento/([a-z,0-9,A-Z,_-]+)/([0-9]+)?$ evento.php?log=$1&id=$2
```

Funciona

```
RewriteRule ^evenTo/([a-z,0-9,A-Z,_-]+)/([0-9]+)?$ evento.php?log=$1&id=$2
```

Código completo do .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^busca/([a-z,0-9,A-Z,_-]+)/([a-z,0-9,A-Z,_-]+)?$ buscador.php?log=$1&id=$2
RewriteRule ^busca/([a-z,0-9,A-Z,_-]+)/([a-z,0-9,A-Z,_-]+)/([0-9]+)?$ buscador.php?log=$1&id=$2&p=$3
RewriteRule ^local/([a-z,0-9,A-Z,_-]+)/([0-9]+)?$ interna.php?log=$1&id=$2
RewriteRule ^([a-z,0-9,A-Z,_-]+)?$ index.php?cid=$1
RewriteRule ^noticia/([a-z,0-9,A-Z,_-]+)/([0-9]+)?$ noticia.php?log=$1&id=$2
RewriteRule ^evento/([a-z,0-9,A-Z,_-]+)/([0-9]+)?$ evento.php?log=$1&id=$2
RewriteRule ^perfil/([0-9]+)?$ perfil.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^cupom/([0-9]+)?$ cupom.php?id=$1
```

Comment: "funciona" e "não funciona" não é uma informação que ajuda muito. Seria importante dar uma lida em **[ask]** e depois [edit] a pergunta para deixá-la mais completa, com uma explicação melhor do que acontece. E a hora que tiver um tempinho, sugeriria ler o **[tour]** e **[help]**.

Comment: E tens alguma outra regra para `evento` que esteja a quebrar essa? Ou tens os links a apontar para `evenTo` e não te apercebeste?

Answer (score 0):

Não há necessidade dessas vírgulas, e o teu problema é a ordem das declarações. Tente assim:

```
RewriteRule ^busca/([a-z0-9A-Z_-]+)/([a-z0-9A-Z_-]+)?$ buscador.php?log=$1&id=$2
RewriteRule ^busca/([a-z0-9A-Z_-]+)/([a-z0-9A-Z_-]+)/([0-9]+)?$ buscador.php?log=$1&id=$2&p=$3
RewriteRule ^local/([a-z0-9A-Z_-]+)/([0-9]+)?$ interna.php?log=$1&id=$2
RewriteRule ^noticia/([a-z0-9A-Z_-]+)/([0-9]+)?$ noticia.php?log=$1&id=$2
RewriteRule ^evento/([a-z0-9A-Z_-]+)/([0-9]+)?$ evento.php?log=$1&id=$2
RewriteRule ^perfil/([0-9]+)?$ perfil.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^cupom/([0-9]+)?$ cupom.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9A-Z_-]+)?$ index.php?cid=$1
```

coloquei o index.php por último, para que o apache teste todas as outras regras antes de entrar nela, entendeu?